# Delete all items except the item with highest value from a list of arrays

Tags: python, arrays

Let's say I have a list of arrays like:

```
list= [[(1,2),124,10001],[(1,2),124,10002],[(1,2),124,10003][(1,2),101,10001],...]
```

How could one extract all arrays with, in this case, the value 124 and sort these arrays by their last value and keep only the highest (here:10003). So that I'm left with:

```
list=[[(1,2),124,10003],[(1,2),101,10001],...]
```

Comment: Why is `[(1,2),101,10001]` in the result? 101 is not the highest nor 10001.

Comment: Because i want to keep the highest of the arrays with 124. the rest should be unaffected.

Comment: Your python isn't valid. Is it a list of lists? Btw. using `l` as a variable name is discouraged. Anyway, couldn't you just sort the list by the 3rd element in each nested list and pick the first or last? E.g. `sorted(l, key=lambda x : x[2], reverse=True)` which will produce `[[(1, 2), 124, 10003], [(1, 2), 124, 10002], [(1, 2), 124, 10001], [(1, 2), 101, 10001]]`

Comment: i just used a simple example code for my problem. But thanks for pointing out that my example is maybe unclear. It should be a list of arrays(im still a noob in programming). i wanted to get rid of all duplicates of 124, except the array with the higest value of the last entry in that entry.

Comment: One thing to pin down - you say 'highest last value' but those are possibly different. Do you want the highest, or the last? Second, do you have control over these data structures? Instead of a list of lists, you could use a dictionary and only overwrite the value if it's larger than the current one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My attempt, with big disclaimer: this is my understanding of your question:

- have a list of lists of 3 elements: tuple, first index, second index
- you would like to select one first index value (e.g. 124) and implode it - remove all items with first index is equal to chosen value, keeping only that with highest value of second index.

code:

```
l = [[(1,2),124,10001], [(1,2),124,10002], [(1,2),124,10003], [(1,2),101,10001]]

def implode_max(my_key, my_list):
    yield max(filter(lambda x: x[1] == my_key, my_list), key=lambda x: x[2])
    yield next(filter(lambda x: x[1] != my_key, my_list))
    # yield next(iter(filter(lambda x: x[1] != my_key, my_list)))  # python 2
    # or
    # for el in filter(lambda x: x[1] != my_key, my_list):
    #     yield el

# this function is a generator, so to print it we need to materialize it
# but for your needs maybe iterator is better
print(list(implode_max(124, l)))
```

This should work on python 2 and 3, however on 3 it will be faster, as filter returns iterators, so less memory is used.

First we filter to get only those elements that we would like to implode, than we find one element we would like to keep, then - yied-ing it.

Second we filter for all other elements and we yiedl-ing them one by one.

**However**

If your question is to implode all of the elements grouped by first index, my solution will not be so nice:

```
l = [[(1,2),124,10001], [(1,2),124,10002], [(1,2),124,10003], [(1,2),101,10001], [(1,2),101,9999]]

tmp_dict = {}

for e in l:
    if e[1] not in tmp_dict or tmp_dict[e[1]][2] < e[2]:
        tmp_dict[e[1]] = e

result = tmp_dict.values()
```

Here we are using a temporary dictionary to have random access to elements indexed by first index, in a dictionary we keep only elements with highest second index.

Comment: That is exactly how i meant it :) What does the "yield next..." part do?

Comment: @user3759978 first `yield` is working as normal "return this element", second one is taking elements one by one (using `next`) from generator, if there would not be `next` it will return a whole flltered array in python 2 or "filter object" in python 3 ([some docs](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators)) (mark it as an answer if this is what you wanted :) )

Comment: This is some awesome stuff. Thx!

Comment: On Python 2.7 the first code sample throws an error on line 5: `TypeError: list object is not an iterator`.

Comment: @RuslanBes yep, this is because filter is not returning iterator - wrap it in `iter`

Answer (score 0):

Not the most pythonic way but it still does the trick:

```
l = [[(1,2),124,10001],[(1,2),124,10002],[(1,2),124,10003],[(1,2),101,10001]]

l.sort(key=lambda x: x[2], reverse=True)
l.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])
pr = None
lmax = []

for i in l:
    if i[1] != pr:
        lmax.append(i)
    pr = i[1]

print lmax
```

Comment: pythonic or not, sometimes you need to start somewhere! 
`(not i[1] == pr) <==> (i[1] != pr)`

Comment: @Jerzyk can you please explain the difference? The 'not' has lower precedence than == so `not a == b` is equal to `!(a == b)`  which equals to `a != b`. Apparently I am missing something?

Comment: you are doing two operations, first compare and then negate, when you can replace with one operation - compare not equal - not only it make your code faster but it is easier to read